# Meaning of しゃいどったで?

Tags: meaning, dialects, contractions, parsing

The speaker says the following:

> 二人ともオメデトさん！コイツ久々に着物新調する言うてエライはしゃいどったで？

He points to his colleague standing behind him who responds with:

> 今あたしの話はいいでしょう…！？

I find the speaker's line very confusing. Though I've tried to look online I still can't figure out what しゃいどったで means. Can someone explain this to me, I'd really like to know what he's saying here.

Answer (score 4):

It is 「**は**しゃいどったで」 and not 「しゃいどったで」.

> 「はしゃいどったで」

is a Kansai way of saying:

> 「はしゃいでいたよ」

「はしゃぐ/燥{はしゃ}ぐ」 means "to make merry", "to be in high spirits", etc.  The word should be in your dictionary; Do try looking it up.  It is a common word.

The sentence-ender 「で」 in Kansai means 「よ」 in Kanto.

So, 「はしゃいどったで」 means "(she) was in high spirits".

「エライ」 means "greatly", "really", etc. in Kansai.

> "Congratulations, both of you!  She/This Girl was in such high spirits, saying she was going to buy a new kimono for the first time in ages!"
>
> "Do you have to talk about me now?"

Comment: Oh I see, thank you! I thought the は was just a topic particle here, so that's how I ended up confusing myself then.